# VS2015 - Cordova - Apk sign with KeyStore build.json

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio, cordova

I am trying to sign my `app-unsigned.apk` with `build.json`.
I created the `keystore` through console and my `build.json` has:

```
{
 "android": {
     "debug": {
         "keystore": "C:\\\\Users\\Matteo.GXITALIA\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\VSOnline\\CREAM\\Mobile\\release.keystore#",
         "storePassword": "***",
         "alias": "release_alias",
         "password" : "***",
         "keystoreType": ""
     }
 }
```

But, when I try to build return me a generic error:

> cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 building one of the platforms    1

Comment: try with debug and release config, also in build.json

Comment: Also facing this same problem - did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit build.json by the binary editor. Remove the periods at the beginning of the file. If it doesn't work , replace the absolute filepath with only the filename, and place the keystore in the project folder.